# How to do button who connected via http protocol?

Tags: android, http, httprequest, iot

I building application IoT to control Bulb via own android App. Module which used is Sonoff Basic with firmware open source. Protocol http connected for a browser. Now the same must be implementation to own app. I have problem with writing code, I don't know what to do to connected. I trying data binding but without result, I need this application for my engineering project. My version code show it:

main_activity.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="button1"

        android:text="@string/on"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>'
```

Java:

```
MainActivity.java

   ' package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import static android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.get;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );



    }

    public void button1( View view ) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.20/?device=relay&name=lampa&command=on");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine; while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { System.out.println(inputLine);
        } in.close();

    }
}'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour to learn how Stack Overflow works and read How to Ask on how to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: you forgot to give a name to your button and add Button button = findviewbyid(R.id.button_name) to your onCreate

Comment: Add name button ande Button button = findbyid . . .    and didn't work :(